# Aligning different for each pair of equations in same align-environment

Tags: align

I am using the following environment and want to have alignment for each the first two, the second two and the third two equations at the =-Symbol. In this moment everything aligns at the same point but this way the last equation for instance is too far on the left. What would you suggest?
Splitting it up in three align-environments doesn't help as then the seperation between the equations would be too big.

```
\begin{align}
    Cov\left(\tilde{c}_D,\tilde{r}_M\right) &= \sum_{i=1}^4f_i\left(c_{D,i}-E(\tilde{c}_D)\right)\left(r_{M,i}-E(\tilde{r}_M)\right),\\
    Cov\left(\tilde{c}_E,\tilde{r}_M\right) &= \sum_{i=1}^4f_i\left(c_{E,i}-E(\tilde{c}_E)\right)\left(r_{M,i}-E(\tilde{r}_M)\right),\\
    V_D &= \frac{E(\tilde{c}_D) - \left( E\left(\tilde{r}_M\right) - r_f\right)\frac{Cov\left(\tilde{c}_D,\tilde{r}_M\right)}{\sigma_{\tilde{r}_M}^2}}{1+r_f},\\
    V_U &= \frac{E(\tilde{c}_E) - \left( E\left(\tilde{r}_M\right) - r_f\right)\frac{Cov\left(\tilde{c}_E,\tilde{r}_M\right)}{\sigma_{\tilde{r}_M}^2}}{1+r_f},\\
    \mu_D &= \frac{E(\tilde{c}_D)}{V_D} - 1 \text{~und~}\\
    \mu_E &= \frac{E(\tilde{c}_E)}{V_E} - 1.
\end{align}
```

Comment: For future questions: You really should make your code minimal working examples (MWE). A MWE is compilable and creates the described problem. It starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}` and includes all packages that are needed for your code (but not more).

Answer (score 3):

ok, I found a solution by myself as I googled for another problem. This helps:

```
\begin{gather}
    \begin{align}
        Cov\left(\tilde{c}_D,\tilde{r}_M\right) &= \sum_{i=1}^4f_i\left(c_{D,i}-E(\tilde{c}_D)\right)\left(r_{M,i}-E(\tilde{r}_M)\right),\\
        Cov\left(\tilde{c}_E,\tilde{r}_M\right) &= \sum_{i=1}^4f_i\left(c_{E,i}-E(\tilde{c}_E)\right)\left(r_{M,i}-E(\tilde{r}_M)\right),
    \end{align}\\
    \begin{align}
        V_D &= \frac{E(\tilde{c}_D) - \left( E\left(\tilde{r}_M\right) - r_f\right)\frac{Cov\left(\tilde{c}_D,\tilde{r}_M\right)}{\sigma_{\tilde{r}_M}^2}}{1+r_f},\\
        V_U &= \frac{E(\tilde{c}_E) - \left( E\left(\tilde{r}_M\right) - r_f\right)\frac{Cov\left(\tilde{c}_E,\tilde{r}_M\right)}{\sigma_{\tilde{r}_M}^2}}{1+r_f},
    \end{align}\\
    \begin{align}
        \mu_D &= \frac{E(\tilde{c}_D)}{V_D} - 1 \text{~und~}\\
        \mu_E &= \frac{E(\tilde{c}_E)}{V_E} - 1.
    \end{align}
\end{gather}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It works: the `amsmath` documentation explains (well hidden in the last part about error messages) "the chief exception is that `align` and most of its variants can be used inside the `gather` environment".

Comment: @campa sigh I wonder who's maintaining amsmath these days:-) (thanks I'll delete the comment)

Comment: Add `\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}` to your preamble and use `\Cov` in the formulas. Each of the `\left` and `\right` you have here should be omitted.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest some improvements: using `subequations` since the equations go in pairs,medium-sized fractions from `nccmath` for fractions in fractions, declare `Cov` as a math operator (for now, `Cov` looks like the product of three variables), and another placement of the word ‘und’ with the `ArrowBetweenLines` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
      \Cov\left(\tilde{c}_D,\tilde{r}_M\right) & = ∑_{i=1}⁴f_i\left(c_{D,i}-E(\tilde{c}_D)\right)\left(r_{M,i}-E(\tilde{r}_M)\right), \\
      \Cov\left(\tilde{c}_E,\tilde{r}_M\right) & = ∑_{i=1}⁴f_i\left(c_{E,i}-E(\tilde{c}_E)\right)\left(r_{M,i}-E(\tilde{r}_M)\right),
    \end{align}
  \end{subequations}
  \\
  \begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
      V_D & = \frac{E(\tilde{c}_D) - \left( E\left(\tilde{r}_M\right) - r_f\right)\mfrac{\Cov\left(\tilde{c}_D,\tilde{r}_M\right)}{\sigma_{\tilde{r}_M}²}}{1+r_f}, \\
      V_U & = \frac{E(\tilde{c}_E) - \left( E\left(\tilde{r}_M\right) - r_f\right)\mfrac{\Cov\left(\tilde{c}_E,\tilde{r}_M\right)}{\sigma_{\tilde{r}_M}²}}{1+r_f},
    \end{align}
  \end{subequations}\\
  \begin{subequations}
    \begin{alignat}{2}
        & & \mu_D & = \frac{E(\tilde{c}_D)}{V_D} - 1 \\
      \ArrowBetweenLines[\text{und~}]
        & & \mu_E & = \frac{E(\tilde{c}_E)}{V_E} - 1.
    \end{alignat}
  \end{subequations}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]